# Checking if tests are being built in a Cargo build script

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I've run into the issue https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2549, "cfg!(test) doesn't seem to work for build.rs". As said there,

```
fn main() {
    if cfg!(test) { ... }
}
```

doesn't work as expected and `cfg!(feature="test")` does. However, this means for me that tests always need to be run with `--features=test`. Is it possible to work around this by enabling the feature by default for tests? Or some other way?

I've also looked at the [Cargo environment variables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html), but the only one which seems to be helpful is

> `CARGO_BIN_EXE_<name>` — The absolute path to a binary target's executable. This is only set when building an integration test or benchmark.

Unfortunately, I am interested exactly in unit tests.